# Safari inspector doesn't show javascript errors

Tags: javascript, safari, macos-high-sierra, macos-mojave

For some reason, since High Sierra and now Mojave, Safari no longer shows page breaking errors in the Inspector console. If I load a page that has a fatal error there is nothing output to the console. Other errors, such as cross origin blocking, 'XMLHttpRequest cannot load' or 'Failed to load resource:' errors DO show up however anything like a reference error or plain broken code show nothing. If the same page is loaded in Chrome or even in Safari Technology Preview it works as expected—displaying the appropriate error in the console. Is there a preference somewhere I've inadvertently switched? It's driving me nuts.